# Why does ^C behave differently from ESC when exiting visual block substitution?

Tags: visual-block, escape

I've started using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> instead of <kbd>ESC</kbd> in vim because of its position on the keyboard and better responsiveness. It mostly behaves the same except when exiting visual block replacements.

I am hoping someone can explain why and  possibly propose a fix/workaround.

Consider the following:

```
<C-v>jjjsmy replacement text<ESC>
```

versus

```
<C-v>jjjsmy replacement text<C-c>
```

With <kbd>ESC</kbd>, `my replacement text` appears on all 4 lines. With <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, `my replacement text` only shows up on the first line. What is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first they might do the same but internally they are interpreted differently.  In layman's terms they mean something like this:

- <kbd>Esc</kbd>: "OK I am done (with whatever I was doing)."
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>: "Stop that as fast as possible!"

It is not clearly documented (as far as I can see) but there are some indications:

- [`i_<esc>`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-[) says "End ... mode" whereas [`i_CTRL-C`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-C) says "Quit insert mode"
- [`i_CTRL-C`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-C) does not expand abbreviations and does not fire the `InserLeave` autocommand.
- Sadly [`v_CTRL-C`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#v_CTRL-C) and [`ì_<Esc>`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_%3CEsc%3E) are less clear, both say "quit".
- When you are in block insert mode (like in the question) you only see the characters you type on the first line.  Only later when you finish (with <kbd>Esc</kbd>) will the text appear in the other lines.  And <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> seems to "abort" before that.
- You might know <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> from the shell where it sends
  `SIGINT` which normally terminates a command.

Comment: True. Taking that further, `:h i_CTRL-c` says `...does not trigger the InsertLeave autocommand event`. Maybe `InsertLeave` is what triggers `{Visual}s` to finish? Doesn't really say. Maybe I can rig it so that the `InsertLeave` event happens even with `<C-c>`.

Comment: you say ctrl-c gives "better responsiveness," but this is the real problem.  escape or ctrl-[ should happen immediately.  if it doesn't something else is wrong with your config

Comment: @Mass I had always assumed that the delay was because Vim needs to wait to make sure my Esc (or `c-[`) is not part of an escape sequence (e.g. arrow keys). How does one configure around that? Note: this only affects terminal vim.

Comment: @Lombard `ttimeoutlen` will let you configure the length of the delay. In Vim it defaults to 100ms, but you could safely drop it to 50ms (Neovim default) or lower.

Comment: @lombard, @zeroknight is correct, except if you have a vimrc it actually defaults to 1000ms (one second).  if you do `set ttimeout ttimeoutlen=50` you should see a big improvement